# Right anti join in Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to perform right anti join in Dataflow?

I can see joins in Dataflow but I didn't find right anti join .

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AFAIK**, **Currently Anti joins are not supported in Data flows**. Only the following joins are supported.

[image]

If your Source tables are from SQL, its good if you perform a stored procedure at source for Right anti join in Dataflow.

If not, you can try the below workaround using **Exists transformation**.

**Exists transformation** takes left and Right streams and **gives the records of left records which are not in Right stream**.(***Left Anti join***)

To achieve Right anti join, you can change the incoming streams.

**Sample demo:**

Left source data:

[image]

Right source data:

[image]

**Exists transformation:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: it's looks like left anti join . I already seen this type of question in SO. If changing the Source data is the solution then what is the purpose of introducing left and right joins. Simply we can use left join right. But I am accepting your answer for your efforts.

Comment: As Anti Joins are not supported in ADF, you can try like this also **only if you want to get the output as Array of objects**. First get the Right outer join and Inner join in two dataflows. Using Dataflow lookup get the two arrays of objects. Then in ADF you can use combination of ForEach and if activities to filter the required records from Right outer array.